# SSN randomization: how many numbers are available?

Tags: statistics

The [Social Security Administration Number Randomization Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.ssa.gov/employer/randomizationfaqs.html) states that

> The nine-digit SSN will eventually be exhausted. The previous SSN
> assignment process limited the number of SSNs that were available for
> assignment to individuals in each state. Randomization affords the SSA
> the opportunity to extend the number of SSNs available for assignment
> for many years.

Social Security Number (SSN) number randomization started in 2011 and the FAQ stresses that

> "The SSA will not reassign SSNs. Randomization will provide us
> with enough new numbers to avoid reassignment."

How many total SSNs - in the current nine digit format - are available with this "randomization" method?

Is the number of possible SSN's impossible to calculate not knowing the SSA's methods or algorithm?

Comment: I don't think this is a math problem, at least not as it stands.  As you are aware, there are $10^9$ possible nine digit strings.  Are some of these excluded?  Well, if so, we'd need to know the exclusion rules.  I don't see what randomization has to do with it.

Comment: Thanks, there have been 450+ million numbers assigned so far. I don't know the exclusion rules. Could we say that 450 million have been excluded from 10 to the ninth? Ten to the ninth is a billion?

Comment: Yes, $10^9$ is a billion.  I have no idea what the exclusion rules are.  I thought that some of the digits contained specific information relevant to time and place of birth, but I might be wrong (or the rules might have changed).  In any case, it's not something one can usefully think about abstractly.  Perhaps they publish their rules...anyway, I'd start by trying to look the rules up.

Comment: [here](https://www.ssa.gov/history/ssn/geocard.html#:~:text=The%20nine%2Ddigit%20SSN%20is,digits%20is%20the%20Serial%20Number) is some information, but it doesn't appear to be complete.